# Are neural correlates of consciousness and immortal souls compatible?

Tags: consciousness, neurophilosophy, souls

Can one be a hard-boiled believer in [neural correlates of consciousness](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/89748/27928) and at the same time believe in things like

- [the immortal soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_mortalism#Immortality_of_the_soul)
- [reincarnation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reincarnation)
- [telepathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telepathy)

and if so, which approaches have been taken to reconcile these beliefs?

Who are the most prominent (neuro-)scientists that don't exclude the possibility of immortal souls, reincarnation, or telepathy - and on which grounds (when not relying on miracles)?

[image]

Comment: Certainly telepathy is theoretically compatible with physicalism. It’s not true (it’s been tested for a century with null results) but it’s a valid hypothesis not requiring supernatural axioms. Same with “reincarnation” if you count “mine uploading” or “mind transfer” as reincarnation and allow it may be possible by technical means (eg molecule-for-molecule reconstruction of a brain or brain/body pair).

Comment: I'd like to exclude "artificial" kinds of reincarnation (like "molecule-for-molecule reconstruction") and telepathy (like "technical read-out of 'thoughts' from one brain and transferring them technically to another brain"). I mean "natural" kinds of reincarnation and telepathy.

Comment: The natural telepathy part I was arguing is compatible with physicalism with no artificial intervention. It’s a valid hypothesis which can be tested empirically using sound scientific methodology, not requiring dualism or supernatural assumptions, etc. In fact, it has been, a lot (without success). But it’s compatible with physicalism. Reincarnation, I’ll grant, is not compatible if we don’t admit artificial intervention.

Comment: @DanBron: Could you please give me a reference where I can learn why telepathy is a valid hypothesis but reincarnation is not? (For me it's not at all clear how even telepathy could be a valid hypothesis.)

Comment: I suppose an existence proof is enough? There have been a number of high-profile and well-funded research groups within prestigious institutions (eg PEAR at Princeton) dedicated to the scientific study of psi phenomena (including telepathy, among others). There are no such institutions studying reincarnation, so far as I know.

Comment: You mean, any performed experiment or study presupposes a valid hypothesis - and so I just have to look at such studies? And if I don't find a study on reincarnation this means that nobody found the hypothesis of reincarnation valid?

Comment: I mean you could read the papers published by these institutions and decide for yourself, but these aren’t random new age nuts writing manifestos in shacks, these are credentialed scientists in prestigious institutions. Who explicitly reject supernatural axioms in their methodologies. Many, many of them. For a century. With entire journals dedicated to their fields. Etc.

Comment: Thanks, I got the picture (which doesn't deviate so much from mine).That means: Telepathy was found to be a valid hypothesis (but rejected), reincarnation was not - not to talk about the immortality of souls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103297/discussion-between-hans-peter-stricker-and-dan-bron).

Comment: I do not even see what is there to be reconciled. The standard Cartesian dualism with immaterial soul acting through material brain implies that there are correlates of its activities in that brain. Nothing prevents it from being immortal, reincarnating or communicating with other souls immaterially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer to this question is to remember that correlation does not equal causation. Neural correlates are exactly that: biological phenomena that correlate with subjective experiences of consciousness. We have no clear idea (yet) what produces (causes) the subjective experience of consciousness, and so we have no theory on which to base a methodological approach to the question. We cannot exclude the possibility of an immortal soul on rational or empirical grounds. Nor can we defend the possibility. This question is currently outside the horizon of proper scientific investigation.

Comment: Somehow happy to hear that - because  it leaves possibilities open.

Comment: Interesting answer, but somehow strikes me as a little unhelpful because you only address the hard problem of consciousness (i.e. how subjectivity arises at all, which we have no materialist account for as is). Doesn't the immaterial soul claim to be more than just this subjectivity-providing mechanism? If we're talking about a soul that can somehow float out of the body at death, I don't see how that would be compatible with the fact that we have a good idea of how physical activities in the brain shape consciousness, even if we don't have an account of how consciousness arises.

Comment: @natojato — I tend to take a neutral/conservative approach to science, acknowledging its intrinsic self-limitations. Should a soul that 'can float out of the body' exist, it certainly could be the causal source of the neural correlates we observe, in exactly the same sense that Santa Claus (should he exist) could be the causal source of presents appearing under a Christmas tree. There are more obvious mechanisms for the appearance of Christmas presents, so most of us give up the 'Santa' theory. But as of yet there are not any obvious mechanisms for these neural correlates.